# CRM 2011 Plugin for Create Email not triggering on Pre-validation

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm relatively new to the CRM SDK, and I'm trying to write a plugin to alter From/CC fields of an email on Create.  It seems when this is registered in Pre-operation, the ActivityParty collection cannot be modified(though things like subject and body can be modified), and [this post](http://mscrmuk.blogspot.com.au/2011/07/partylist-attributes-and-plugin-event.html) recommended setting the pipeline stage to Pre-validation.

When I do this the plugin no longer gets triggered.  I know this because when remote debugging, breakpoints are only hit when pre-operation is selected.  Also, when not remote debugging, none of the other changes get implemented in the plugin code.

Does anyone know what might be preventing this plugin from executing?

Answer (score 0):

When you register plugin on Create message fields To, CC, BCC will be empty. Try register on [DeliverIncoming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb959405.aspx) / [DeliverPromote](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb959406.aspx) messages

Comment: I have played around with DeliverIncoming, but it only allows me to create/delete email addresses - I'm trying to add/remove ActivityParty objects.  The issue I have is that several contacts have the same email address, and when one contact sends an email, CRM links to all contacts.  I want to remove some of the contacts linked to the email based on some business rules.